# Why is the MySQL integer comparison is slower than datetime null comparison?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, where-clause

I'm using MySQL 5.7.

There is a table called `transactions` with over 3 million records. The table schema is as follows:

1. `id` - INT (autoincrements)
2. `deleted_at` (DATETIME, NULL allowed)
3. `record_status` (TINYINT, DEFAULT value is 1)
4. Other columns pertaining to this table...

The `record_status` is an integer version of the `deleted_at`. When a record is deleted, the value is set to 0. An index is also created for this column.

The null based DATETIME query takes `740 ms` to execute:

`select transactions.id from transactions where transactions.deleted_at is null`

The TINYINT based query takes `15.1 s` to execute:

`select transactions.id from transactions where transactions.record_status = 1`

Isn't the check on the TINYINT column (with index) supposed to be faster? Why is this happening?

[EDIT]

**Added information about the table's performance**

To take the experiment further, all unnecessary columns were removed from the table. Only the following persist.

1. `id` - INT (autoincrements)
2. `deleted_at` (DATETIME, NULL allowed)
3. `record_status` (TINYINT, DEFAULT value is 1)
4. `transaction_time` (DATETIME)

Query 1: Takes 2.3ms

```
select transactions.id from transactions
where transactions.record_status = 1 limit 1000000;
```

Query 2: Takes 2.1ms

```
select transactions.id from transactions 
where transactions.deleted_at is null limit 1000000;
```

Query 3: **Takes 20 seconds**

```
select transactions.id from transactions 
where transactions.record_status = 1 
and transaction_time > '2020-04-01' limit 1000;
```

Query 4: Takes 500ms

```
select transactions.id from transactions 
where transactions.deleted_at is null 
and transaction_time > '2020-04-01' limit 1000;
```

Query 5: 394ms

```
select transactions.id from transactions
where transaction_time > '2020-04-01' limit 1000000;
```

I'm unable to figure out why Query 3 is taking this long.

Comment: (1) These do not do the same thing.  (2) The time for a query depends on the amount of data returned.  (3) My best guess is that `record_status` is not actually indexed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: The record_status is indexed.

Comment: Cold/hot data? Do you get any difference if you run each query twice?

Comment: @jarlh: Tried several times before posting. Observation is consistent.

Comment: Update statistics? Data distribution etc?

Comment: @jarlh: I've added some details to the question. Please let me know if any of it helps.

Comment: @PraveenSelvam . . . An index on a `tinyint` is likely not to be very selective so the optimizer might ignore it.

Comment: Agreed Gordon. Just did it, so as to rule out the aspect of index being a possible solution.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- there could be subtle details that are missing.

Comment: And, how many rows are returned in each case?  (Delivering 1000000 rows takes longer than 1 row.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was addressed by adding a composite index.

Both the following now result in fast performance.

1. Composite key on `transaction_time` and `deleted_at`.
2. Composite key on `transaction_time` and `record_status`.

Thanks to @Gordon Linoff and @jarlh. Their suggestions led to this finding.

Comment: And EVERY insert, update or delete to the table will take some amount of time to keep these 2 new indexes current.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm still assessing the impact of the change. Depending on the numbers, I'll be choosing the key with either the integer column, or the datetime column.

Comment: Both of those suggestions are backward.  Put the "range" column last.  (`deleted_at IS NULL` works like a simple '=')  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
select transactions.id from transactions 
where transactions.record_status = 1 
and transaction_time > '2020-04-01' limit 1000;
```

cannot be optimized without a composite index like this -- in this order:

```
INDEX(record_status, transaction_time)
```

(No, two separate single-column indexes will not work as well.)